# Where to place a downloaded file to install a NIC driver?

Tags: software-installation

I need to install a driver for an Atheros wired NIC. But since I do not have a connection through Ubuntu, I will have to make a download from my WinXP PC. Once I have the download and can transfer it to my Ubuntu PC, where should I place it to make the install?

Answer (score 0):

If you would've downloaded the file from Ubuntu, it would go into the Downloads folder.  So when you copy it from your Windows machine, you can put it in the Downloads folder, or any folder of your choice, as long as you remember it.

Then once its in your Ubuntu machine, you can go ahead and make the install.